# Crashing when trying to insert a value in an array of strings when reading from a CSV file

Tags: c++, csv

I am working on this C++ program to read csv files in a specific format. The said files are formatted as follows:

> 01.01.2015;2.6
>
> 02.01.2015;5.7
>
> 03.01.2015;3.1

I have created a program to read into the file and insert the values into a struct using an overloaded operator >>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct data {
    int day, mon, yea;
    double temp;
};

istream& operator >> (istream & input, data & c){
     char poi, sem;
     input >> c.day >> poi >> c.mon >> poi >> c.yea >> sem >> c.temp;
     return input;
}

int getDay(){
    data c;
    return c.day;
}

int getMon(){
     data c;
     return c.mon;
}
double getTemp(){
     data c;
     return c.temp;
}

int readWeather (string fileName, string tempData[31][12]){
    data c;
    stringstream tempStream;

    ifstream weatherFile;

    weatherFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (weatherFile.is_open()==false){
        cerr << "Error opening file!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "File opened." << endl;
        while (!weatherFile.eof()){
            weatherFile >> c;
            tempStream << getTemp();
            tempData[getDay()-1][getMon()-1]=tempStream.str();
        }
    }
    weatherFile.close();
    cout << "File closed." << endl;
    return c.yea;
}

int main() {
    data c;
    string file;
    string temp[31][12]={""};

    cout << "Input CSV file to be processed." << endl;
    cin >> file;
    string fileDir = "C:\\" + file + ".csv";
    readWeather(fileDir,temp);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code does not return any errors, but when it reaches the line

```
tempData[getDay()-1][getMon()-1]=tempStream.str();
```

the program crashes.
My question is does anyone know what is wrong with that particular line? or maybe there is something wrong with my general code?

P.S. I am fairly new to C++, any additional suggestions would be really great.

Answer (score 1):

All of your getter functions return uninitialised variables. eg:

```
int getDay(){
   data c;
   return c.day;
}
```

In this function you declare a local object `c` and then return a value from it which is never initialised.

I would suggest this is a good time to learn how to use your debugger. It will show you where you are going wrong very quickly in this case.

Comment: I did not initialize it because I thought that I would be getting it from the file. However I did run a debugger and it gave a SIGSEGV error, it turns out that there's a "segmentation fault".  If I understand correctly, what I did wrong is that line allocates the arrays to a memory space that doesn't belong to me or doesn't exist, cmiiw though.